# Is the associated algebra of a quadratic filtered algebra again quadratic

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, graded-rings-modules, associated-graded, filtered-algebras

Let $A$ be a [filtered quadratic algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_algebra). Let $G(A)$ be the associated graded algebra. Will $G(A)$ again be a quadratic algebra or can higher relations appear when passing to the graded seeting?

EDIT: Given the comments below (thanks a lot to YCor and Leonid), it seems that the answer is negative. So what might be a set of reasonable assumptions on the algebra and the filtration to guarantee that the graded algebra is quadratic.

Comment: In the context of Lie algebras (nilpotent Lie algebras, with filtration induced by the lower central series) I think I saw examples (where the associated graded is not quadratic) — unfortunately I don't remember where — maybe in computations I did myself. It's not surprising since typically the cohomology is enlarged when passing to the associated graded.

Comment: @YCor As I understood OP's question, judging by his reference to a Wikipedia article, his context is that of increasing filtrations, not decreasing ones.  But the analogy still applies, and the answer surely must be negative in general.

Comment: If the question is posed in such general terms -- I am not sure that I ever met a counterexample in the literature.  But the answer surely must be negative, in the sense that the associative graded algebra need not be quadratic.

Comment: It should be a good exercise for a graduate student interested in quadratic algebras (who is, e.g., looking into my book with Polishchuk or some such literature).  To come up with an example of a system of non-Koszul nonhomogeneous quadratic relations which are self-consistent in degree less or equal to 3 (so they correspond to a quadratic CDG-algebra via nonhomogeneous quadratic duality) but computations, say, in degree less or equal to 4 ("resolving ambiguities in degree 4" or whatever they call it nowadays) lead to a nontrivial relation of degree 3 in the associated graded algebra.

Comment: The point of the exercise is that one has to make sure that "resolving ambiguities in higher degrees" does not lead to any new relations of degrees 2 and lower, but does produce a nontrivial relation of degree 3.

Comment: Re EDIT: The answer to this question is provided by the Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem for nonhomogeneous quadratic/Koszul algebras.  See my paper "Nonhomogeneous quadratic duality and curvature" in FAA-1993, https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1982 , Section 3.3, or for a more detailed exposition, my book with A. Polishchuk titled "Quadratic algebras", Chapter 5.  This is a nontrivial theorem with a not-so-easy formulation and a not-so-straightforward proof.

Comment: @Leonid: If you put this as an answer I will accept it.